# How can I get the minimum value of a column when other column is null?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, missing-data

It's a pretty direct question, let's say I have:

```
id        grade     coldate
123       100       2020-01-01
444       45        2020-02-01
NULL      55        2020-03-01
NULL      70        2020-04-01
```

I want the worst grade considering only when the id is null. So even though 444 has a lower grade than the id in the third row, the output I am expecting is 55. If possible, I wanted to bring the row number as well.

Any idea? A simple filter wouldn't work because is not like I'm looking for something that attend two conditions. I thought about writing a function, but it would be too much work (I would first list all null values and store in a list and then get the minimum from a dataframe filtering only those in the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this oneliner:

```
df.loc[df['id'].isna(), 'grade'].min()
```

Output:

```
55
```

Use `loc` with booleans series where column, 'id', `isna` and get the `min` value for
column, 'grade'.

Answer (score 1):

this returns a dataframe with one row satisfying the given conditions

```
df1=df[df['id']==NULL]
df1[df1['grade']==df1['grade'].min()]
```